# Is there an ADB command to change the advanced settings of an installed application?

Tags: android, command-line, permissions, adb

I have been trying to figure out a command using ADB command line to change the advanced settings of an application I am installing through ADB.

Once installed I wish to change the following settings to 'allow' by using an ADB command:

[image]

Is this possible?

I thought it might be: [found here](https://dev.to/larsonzhong/most-complete-adb-commands-4pcg#application-management) 
adb shell pm grant com.mycompany.mypackage INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command for the Install unknown apps would be:

```
adb shell pm grant com.company.testapp  android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
```

Which will fail, because `android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` is not a changeable permission type:

```
Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES is not a changeable permission type
```

Maybe there is a way around this, that I don't know of.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
appops set com.mycompany.mypackage REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES allow
```

It works for my device with Android 10.